# Flatten POJO for individual fields

Tags: java, json, flatten

So basically trying to take a POJO which has objects nested throughout it, and return a string value, prefixed with each OBJECT name followed by a "."

So if we had a java class called Request and we created a new Request object called cardRequest, that object contains a parameter of type PartyInformation, and that object contacts a parameter type Address and that object containts a String value streetName. We would then create a function to accept a String value and it would return:

Essentially you are converting a JSON nested type structure to a flattened string for that particular field name

```
"cardRequest.partyInformation.address.streetName"
```

Make sense?

*EDIT*

There seems to be some confusion. Basically I want to take a JSON type POJO structure and flatten it out. So imagine :

```
{
    "cardRequest": {
        "partyInformation": {
            "address": {
                "streetName": "Park Ave"
                "streetNumber": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the request in JSON format but I can have that as a Java object. And that's how we do it in out service. We now have a CardRequest object with the name cardRequest. Now, I want to find a built in function or build a function that when I pass in streetName String variable it returns the flattened nested structure of that String variable...so again...would return....

```
"cardRequest.partyInformation.address.streetName"
```

and if I pass in streetNumber to this function it would return:

```
"cardRequest.partyInformation.address.streetNumber"
```

Comment: I'm not getting it...  Could you please give a few more examples, along with the equivalent JSON?

Comment: sure, sorry i should have been a little more detailed. give me a few

Comment: Yes as suggested by @MarkLavin definitely need a json and probably the general structure of your pojo class

Comment: Brian, so what if partyInformation has multiple fields too, what to do with them? Are you assuming there is only one field in each of the subclasses?

Comment: Just edited with more information. Sorry about that. And to answer the most recent comment, that's fine. That's a separate field in the partyInformation Object and shouldn't matter